# I used to be able to double click on my outlook calendar to create an event. Now I have to right click to add a new event

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I used to be able to double click on my outlook calendar to create an event, now I have to right click and then click on add new event.  Did I accidentally change something in outlook?

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you using?  Double-click works for me in Outlook 365.

Comment: Outlook, Calendar, New Item - Just click ONCE in the newest Outlook Version.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur in Outlook desktop client or webmail?

If it occurs in Outlook desktop client, have you done any specific operations before that?

And as squillman mentioned, what's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

If the issue still exists, considering that it would also be affected when the Outlook program itself is damaged, it is recommended that you try to [fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.